# Coefficient matrix not invertible with a corARMA model

Tags: r, correlation, moving-average, nlme, autoregressive-models

I am currently working on a project involving the `nlme` package in R. The acf plots are showing that there is autocorrelation, so I've decided to define an autocorrelation structure by using an autoregressive moving average (ARMA) correlation structure.

I am trying to select the best model of the several models I am running, but I am running into issues with corARMA. Here's the chunk of ARMA correlation models I'm running:

```
mod2 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=0, q=1))
mod3 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=1, q=0))
mod4 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=0, q=2))
mod5 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=2, q=0))
mod6 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=1, q=2))
mod7 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=2, q=1))
mod8 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=2, q=2))
mod9 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=0, q=3))
mod10 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=3, q=0))
mod11 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=1, q=3))
mod12 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=3, q=1))
mod13 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=2, q=3))
mod14 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=3, q=2))
mod15 <-update(GLS_Mod1.1, corr=corARMA(form=~1|INCUB_YEAR, p=3, q=3))
```

`mod7` is returning an error:

```
Error in `coef<-.corARMA`(`*tmp*`, value = value[parMap[, i]]) : 
  Coefficient matrix not invertible
```

`mod8` is also returning the same error.

I'm not sure what this means and how I can get rid of this error. Does it have something to do with the p and q?

UPDATE: I have added a `mod16` which has a p = 1 and a q = 1, yet it is returning the same `Coefficient matrix not invertible` error. Is my dataset/time series just too complicated for `nlme`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.